# PHP array limit of the same type (value)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have multiple arrays which I am using in a foreach loop. I would like to limit what I return in the foreach by the type field value. Then I would like to sort the foreach loop by rating value (highest first).

So in the example below top rated and a limit of 2 of the same types (so it should return 6 results).

```
array(3) {
["id"]=> 1
  ["type"]=> "type1"
  ["rating"]=> "8.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 2
  ["type"]=> "type1"
  ["rating"]=> "10.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 3
  ["type"]=> "type1"
  ["rating"]=> "6.5000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 4
  ["type"]=> "type2"
  ["rating"]=> "6.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 5
  ["type"]=> "type2"
  ["rating"]=> "10.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 6
  ["type"]=> "type2"
  ["rating"]=> "6.5000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 7
  ["type"]=> "type3"
  ["rating"]=> "6.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 8
  ["type"]=> "type3"
  ["rating"]=> "10.0000"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=> 9
  ["type"]=> "type3"
  ["rating"]=> "6.5000"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these functions:

```
function sortedByRating($data) {
    $sorted = array();
    foreach($data as $subArray) {
        $sorted[$subArray['id']] = $subArray['rating'];
    }
    asort($sorted);
    $sorted = array_keys($sorted);
    $resultArray = array();
    foreach($data as $subArray) {
        $resultArray[array_search($subArray['id'], $sorted)] = $subArray;
    }
    ksort($resultArray);
    return array_values($resultArray);   
}

function getByType($data, $type) {
    return array_filter($data, function($subArray) use ($type){
        return $subArray['type'] === $type;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u search for array_unique() ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wont be able to limit the values with this? I need to return at least 3 (or in the example above 2) of the same type.

Comment: Hmm, looks like u need sorting ur arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
And ur situation allow combine all of this arrays to one?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter arrays using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        id => 1,
        type => "type1",
        rating => "8.0000"
    ),
    array(
        id => 2,
        type => "type1",
        rating => "10.0000"
    ),
    array(
        id => 3,
        type => "type1",
        rating => "6.5000"
    ),
    array(
        id => 4,
        type => "type2",
        rating => "6.0000"
    ),
    array(
        id => 5,
        type => "type2",
        rating => "10.0000"
    )
);

$type1 = array_filter(
    $data,
    function($elem) {
        return ($elem['type'] === 'type1');
    }
);
```

`$type1` will contain only those elements with `type => "type1"`.

Then you can order any array using [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to sort them by your own comparison function. If you are going to sort by rating, then convert ratings to float when comparing using [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is in $myArr,
You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort your array:

```
<?php
usort($myArr, function($a, $b) {
    return @$a['rating'] - @$b['rating'];
});
```

And since you want 2 and not 1 of each type, you can run through your sorted array and keep counts to keep track of how many you have (you can also do something similar with array_filter or something, but for simplicity I'm keeping it this way):

```
<?php
$finalArr = array();
$counts = array();
foreach ($myArr as $item) {
    if (!isset($counts[$item['type']]))
        $counts[$item['type']] = 0;
    $counts[$item['type']]++;
    if ($counts[$item['type']] < 2)
        $finalArr[] = $item;
}

print_r($finalArr);
```